# Suppress Page Footer Section in Crystal Report in C# .Net

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a crystal report file in that I have two footer section, first
 group footer section and second page footer section. I want to
 suppress page footer section when group footer section is print when
 group change.

How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried using the report footer?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on page footer area -> Section Expert -> Page footer -> Keep Suppress (No Drill-Down) unchecked and click on x+2 button as shown

[image]

In the following editor, write the code that returns true or false according to your condition.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, you can click on the page footer and select section expert, then there will be an option of suppress and against that there is a formula option. You can specify the condition and set the suppress.

```
if(condition)
then true
else
false
```